# Receiving empty objects in a Spring Boot app running in VS Code

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code

I have an app created in Spring Tools Suite, using Spring Boot. It is a simple Rest Controller returning some objects stored in a MongoDB database. The app works fine, if I open a browser or send a GET request in Postman, I can see the objects in JSON format. I'm not using any annotation in the object attributes, except the @Id.
I moved the same code to VSCode, using Spring Boot and Java extensions pack. The app runs as expected, but when I open Postman and send the same request to get all the objects, I receive the **same quantity** of objects, but all of them are empty. I'm using the last versions of all the tools mentioned.
Anyone knows what is happening? Looks like a serialization problem...

Answer (score 0):

had you move the database too? and connected? it seems like just because of your project cann't get the data from database.

Comment: I introduced a console log in my controller, just before returning the data, and the result is an array of empty objects. My test database has only 5 objects, and I receive an array of 5 empty objects.

Comment: Searching a little more in the net, I introduced a JsonFormat annotation above each of my entity's attributes, like `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)`, and now the data is returning. I don`t know why this annotation is necessary (only when using VS Code), but at least is working now.